# “E: The list of sources could not be read.” while trying to update

Tags: 14.04, software-sources

i am get this error while trying to run update command

```
mostafa@mostafa-Satellite-C660:~$ sudo apt-get update
E: Type '<!DOCTYPE' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

How can i solve this? i am using **ubuntu 14.04 LTS**

Comment: Output the content of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list contains HTML code, probably the 404 or 403 HTTP Error message from when you downloaded it from the wrong url :)

Remove that file or replace it with something that looks like this:
`deb http://example.com/whatever trusty main`